# Can I run my desktop without a PSU fan?

Tags: power-supply, fan, desktop-computer

What if I pulled the PSU fan out of the PSU, but all the other fans and heatsinks are still in the PC and running?

Answer (score 1):

Your PSU would over-heat under load, and likely switch off due to the thermal protection circuitry.

Fanless power supplies do exist, but they're designed to operate that way rather than just the fan being removed, as they have a larger heatsink.

BeQuiet have an article on passive/active power supplies [here](https://www.bequiet.com/en/insidebequiet/12).

Comment: Why do I see most of the PSU fans off then?

Comment: Because the fan runs under heavy processing load. That is precisely when the Power Supply needs cooling.

Comment: That depends entirely on where you're looking... if you mean the fan doesn't spin, then the PSU isn't under significant load.